# sqlsrv_connect: use Windows authentication?

Tags: windows, php, authentication

I have a PHP server running under IIS on `serverIIS1`, and a MS SQL database on `serverDB4`. I created some PHP code that runs on the `serverIIS1` server:

```
$serverName = "serverDB4\serverDB4";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DATABASE_NAME", "UID"=>"DOMAIN.ORG\\databaseadm", "PWD"=>"passwordishere");

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

I verified all this info is correct (the login is a Windows account with proper access, so it's via *Windows authentication*), but I'm getting this error:

> Login failed for user 'DOMAIN.ORG\databaseadm'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'DOMAIN.ORG\databaseadm'. )

Why is the login failing? I know the info is right, as I can connect manually remotely via SQL Server Management Studio with those details.

Is it because I'm using Windows authentication? If that does not allow plaintext auth, how can I sqlsrv_connect with a Windows password?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296161(v=SQL.105).aspx) you do not pass the UID and PWD to utilize Windows Authentication. You can see an example [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296205(v=sql.105).aspx).

From remarks within documentation link:

> If values for the UID and PWD keys are not specified in the optional $connectionInfo parameter, the connection will be attempted using Windows Authentication. For more information about connecting to the server, see How to: Connect Using Windows Authentication and How to: Connect Using SQL Server Authentication.

Comment: Yes that's what I started thinking. How can I authenticate with this specific Windows account, since the Windows account that IIS runs under does not have access to the database?

Comment: You configure that within your site in IIS and believe it is the identity configured for the application pool.